# Datatransfermanager windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, file-sharing

I am using

```
DataTranferManager mgr = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
```

But I am getting an exception

> {System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported. at
>   Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView()
>   at ContactsExporter.MainPage..ctor()} System.Exception
>   {System.NotSupportedException}

Does Window Phone 8 sdk really supports this method..?

I have tested this on Windows Phone 8.1 Developer Phone also. But no use.
Can any one suggest me what to do..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager):
This API is supported in native apps only.

Have you tried it in a UNIVERSAL (RT) app for 8.1, not a Silverlight one?

Comment: No, I am still using Visual Studio 2012 so that My App Supports both WP 8 and WP 8.1. I tested using WP8 Emulator and WP 8.1 Lumia Phone. Does "Only Native Support" means, only c++ apps can use it or what..?

Comment: @suneel, That is correct. if you are in Silverlight WP8 level, this will only work in c++.